# ¿Como personalizar un formato de validación con jquery validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Tengo realizada la siguiente función para validacion de alfanumericos

```
$.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[\w.]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Letras y numero solamente por favor ");
```

aplico jquery validate al siguiente formulario:

```
$('#formulario_creacion_multa').validate({
        rules: {
            idboleta: {
                required: true,
                digits:true,
                maxlength:10
            },
            numplaca: {
                required: true,
                alphanumeric:true,
                minlength:7,
                maxlength:7
            }
        },
        messages:{
            idboleta:{
                required: "Por favor ingrese numero de boleta",
                digits: "Por favor ingrese numeros enteros",
                maxlength: "Por favor no ingrese más de 10 digitos"
            },
            numplaca: {
                required: "Por favor ingrese numero de placa",
                maxlength: "Por favor no ingrese más de 7 caracteres",
                minlength: "Por favor ingrese al menos 7 caracteres"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
          console.log("Creacion");
        }
    });
```

El detalle consiste en el campo `numplaca`, ya que este debe validar un formato en especifico: por ejemplo debe aceptar un formato como este: P000ABC, es decir que debe aceptar al inicio una letra, seguido de 3 dígitos luego finalizar con 3 letras ya sean de la A hasta la Z, no debe aceptar guiones medios ni bajos, ni caracteres como la @ o otro símbolo.
¿Como podría resolver tal situación?
De antemano muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice un código en base al tuyo con algunas modificaciones, primero agregué el método **numeroPlaca** donde tienes la regla del número de placa y segundo agregue ese método como una regla personalizada para el campo **numplaca** dentro del método validate:

```js
$.validator.addMethod("numeroPlaca", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /(^[A-Za-z]{1,3})([0-9]{3})([A-Za-z]{3})/.test(value);
}, "El formato para la placa es A000AAA");

$("#form").validate({
  rules: {
    numplaca: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 7,
      maxlength: 9,
      numeroPlaca: ""
    }
  },
  messages:{
    numplaca: {
        required: "Por favor ingrese numero de placa",
        maxlength: "Por favor no ingrese más de 6 caracteres",
        minlength: "Por favor ingrese al menos 10 caracteres"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form id="form" method="post" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Probando una regla personalizada con Jquery Validate</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="numplaca">Placa: </label>
      <input id="numplaca" type="text" name="numplaca" class="numplaca">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias David y si de pronto necesitara que el formato fuera posible primero ingresar 1 a 3 letras, por ejemplo: A000AAA, AA000AAA y AAA000AAA. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Listo ya edite el código puedes probar

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda David, bendiciones.